# Data Execution Prevention of Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, data-execution-prevention

I have Delphi 6 on a computer using VISTA.  It has been running OK for years, but now Windows just sends me a message saying Delphi 32 Development Environment has stopped working and was closed due to Data Execution Prevention.  I tried to change the Data Execution Prevention, but it had no effect

Comment: What changes did you make to the system?

Comment: Also, you are asking about Delphi 6, but you tagged your question as Delphi 2006 instead. Which are you really using?